# I have (.dag) and (.dax) files that have been used by my code. But I don't know how to open them or to create one

Tags: java, cloud, scheduled-tasks, workflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

My code is Workflow scheduling algorithm and this algorithm generally used the DAG's as the input and calculates the cost and least completion time.

**MY QUESTION IS HOW TO OPEN THESE `.dag` FILES? And how to create one? PLEASE Recommend any SOFTWARE!!! I know that I have to use Cloud-Sim but I can't find any. Please help!
Thank You :)**

Now below is the code format `.dag` file of it:

```
FILE Cybershake_PSA.zip 858
FILE FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s00986-h00000 2479038
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00015.grm 24000
FILE FFI_0_2_fy.sgt 19653249125
FILE Cybershake_Seismograms.zip 60245
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00019.bsa 216
FILE FFI_0_1_subfx.sgt 127509443
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00005.grm 24000
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s07623-h00000 2405660
FILE FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s05126-h00000 4247935
FILE FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt 161739326
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s09984-h00000 4001726
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00038.bsa 216
FILE FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s04215-h00000 2728286
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00009.bsa 216
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00038.grm 24000
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00044.grm 24000
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00028.bsa 216
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00028.grm 24000
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s09366-h00000 3100824
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00048.bsa 216
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00042.bsa 216
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00013.bsa 216
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00032.grm 24000
FILE FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s04922-h00000 3054926
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00003.bsa 216
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00032.bsa 216
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00017.grm 24000
FILE FFI_0_1_fy.sgt 19568436372
FILE FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s02512-h00000 4283382
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00007.grm 24000
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s05485-h00000 3358986
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s08006-h00000 2537182
FILE FFI_0_1_subfy.sgt 127509443
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00011.grm 24000
FILE FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s06780-h00000 2517218
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00046.grm 24000
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00044.bsa 216
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00015.bsa 216
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00005.bsa 216
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00034.grm 24000
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00021.grm 24000
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00034.bsa 216
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s01424-h00000 2287823
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s01705-h00000 2198730
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00024.grm 24000
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00024.bsa 216
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00009.grm 24000
FILE FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s08974-h00000 3327774
FILE FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s03651-h00000 5152401
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s04590-h00000 3041611
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s00893-h00000 2065853
FILE FFI_0_2_fx.sgt 19653249125
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s07850-h00000 4809167
FILE FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt 161739326
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00048.grm 24000
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00013.grm 24000
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00019.grm 24000
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00046.bsa 216
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00017.bsa 216
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00036.grm 24000
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00003.grm 24000
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s08935-h00000 3730805
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00042.grm 24000
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00026.grm 24000
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00036.bsa 216
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s09877-h00000 1972767
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00021.bsa 216
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00007.bsa 216
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00040.bsa 216
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00040.grm 24000
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00026.bsa 216
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00011.bsa 216
FILE FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s06648-h00000 2617136
FILE PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00030.bsa 216
FILE FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s03033-h00000 5328495
FILE FFI_0_1_fx.sgt 19568436372
FILE FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s01836-h00000 3982417
FILE Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00030.grm 24000
TASK ID00039 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.08
TASK ID00028 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 46.08
TASK ID00017 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 26.16
TASK ID00006 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.26
TASK ID00040 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 28.80
TASK ID00029 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.21
TASK ID00018 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 0.58
TASK ID00007 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 22.46
TASK ID00041 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.54
TASK ID00030 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 55.07
TASK ID00019 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 55.70
TASK ID00008 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.13
TASK ID00042 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 57.86
TASK ID00031 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 0.62
TASK ID00020 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.49
TASK ID00009 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 26.41
TASK ID00043 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.11
TASK ID00032 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 31.78
TASK ID00021 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 40.46
TASK ID00010 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.58
TASK ID00044 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 26.23
TASK ID00033 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.26
TASK ID00022 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.44
TASK ID00011 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 26.61
TASK ID00000 CyberShake::ZipPSA:1.0 0.31
TASK ID00045 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.34
TASK ID00034 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 30.47
TASK ID00023 CyberShake::ExtractSGT:1.0 152.25
TASK ID00012 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.53
TASK ID00001 CyberShake::ZipSeis:1.0 0.26
TASK ID00046 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 25.92
TASK ID00035 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.15
TASK ID00024 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 63.84
TASK ID00013 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 44.48
TASK ID00002 CyberShake::ExtractSGT:1.0 200.98
TASK ID00047 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 0.58
TASK ID00036 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 64.83
TASK ID00025 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 0.88
TASK ID00014 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.61
TASK ID00003 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 31.85
TASK ID00048 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 35.41
TASK ID00037 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.06
TASK ID00026 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 39.34
TASK ID00015 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 35.16
TASK ID00004 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.56
TASK ID00049 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 0.69
TASK ID00038 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 57.00
TASK ID00027 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 1.20
TASK ID00016 CyberShake::PeakValCalcOkaya:1.0 0.69
TASK ID00005 CyberShake::SeismogramSynthesis:1.0 36.83
INPUTS ID00039 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00038.grm
OUTPUTS ID00039 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00038.bsa
INPUTS ID00028 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s01424-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00028 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00028.grm
INPUTS ID00017 FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s06780-h00000 FFI_0_1_subfx.sgt FFI_0_1_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00017 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00017.grm
INPUTS ID00006 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00005.grm
OUTPUTS ID00006 PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00005.bsa
INPUTS ID00040 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s09984-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00040 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00040.grm
INPUTS ID00029 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00028.grm
OUTPUTS ID00029 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00028.bsa
INPUTS ID00018 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00017.grm
OUTPUTS ID00018 PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00017.bsa
INPUTS ID00007 FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s05126-h00000 FFI_0_1_subfx.sgt FFI_0_1_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00007 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00007.grm
INPUTS ID00041 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00040.grm
OUTPUTS ID00041 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00040.bsa
INPUTS ID00030 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s04590-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00030 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00030.grm
INPUTS ID00019 FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s02512-h00000 FFI_0_1_subfx.sgt FFI_0_1_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00019 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00019.grm
INPUTS ID00008 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00007.grm
OUTPUTS ID00008 PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00007.bsa
INPUTS ID00042 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s01705-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00042 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00042.grm
INPUTS ID00031 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00030.grm
OUTPUTS ID00031 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00030.bsa
INPUTS ID00020 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00019.grm
OUTPUTS ID00020 PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00019.bsa
INPUTS ID00009 FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s04922-h00000 FFI_0_1_subfx.sgt FFI_0_1_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00009 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00009.grm
INPUTS ID00043 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00042.grm
OUTPUTS ID00043 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00042.bsa
INPUTS ID00032 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s07623-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00032 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00032.grm
INPUTS ID00021 FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s04215-h00000 FFI_0_1_subfx.sgt FFI_0_1_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00021 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00021.grm
INPUTS ID00010 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00009.grm
OUTPUTS ID00010 PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00009.bsa
INPUTS ID00044 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s08935-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00044 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00044.grm
INPUTS ID00033 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00032.grm
OUTPUTS ID00033 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00032.bsa
INPUTS ID00022 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00021.grm
OUTPUTS ID00022 PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00021.bsa
INPUTS ID00011 FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s03651-h00000 FFI_0_1_subfx.sgt FFI_0_1_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00011 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00011.grm
OUTPUTS ID00000 Cybershake_PSA.zip
INPUTS ID00045 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00044.grm
OUTPUTS ID00045 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00044.bsa
INPUTS ID00034 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s05485-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00034 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00034.grm
INPUTS ID00023 FFI_0_2_fx.sgt FFI_0_2_fy.sgt FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s06648-h00000
OUTPUTS ID00023 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
INPUTS ID00012 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00011.grm
OUTPUTS ID00012 PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00011.bsa
OUTPUTS ID00001 Cybershake_Seismograms.zip
INPUTS ID00046 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s07850-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00046 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00046.grm
INPUTS ID00035 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00034.grm
OUTPUTS ID00035 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00034.bsa
INPUTS ID00024 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s00893-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00024 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00024.grm
INPUTS ID00013 FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s03033-h00000 FFI_0_1_subfx.sgt FFI_0_1_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00013 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00013.grm
INPUTS ID00002 FFI_0_1_fx.sgt FFI_0_1_fy.sgt FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s04215-h00000
OUTPUTS ID00002 FFI_0_1_subfx.sgt FFI_0_1_subfy.sgt
INPUTS ID00047 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00046.grm
OUTPUTS ID00047 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00046.bsa
INPUTS ID00036 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s08006-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00036 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00036.grm
INPUTS ID00025 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00024.grm
OUTPUTS ID00025 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00024.bsa
INPUTS ID00014 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00013.grm
OUTPUTS ID00014 PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00013.bsa
INPUTS ID00003 FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s08974-h00000 FFI_0_1_subfx.sgt FFI_0_1_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00003 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00003.grm
INPUTS ID00048 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s06648-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00048 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00048.grm
INPUTS ID00037 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00036.grm
OUTPUTS ID00037 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00036.bsa
INPUTS ID00026 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s09366-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00026 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00026.grm
INPUTS ID00015 FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s00986-h00000 FFI_0_1_subfx.sgt FFI_0_1_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00015 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00015.grm
INPUTS ID00004 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00003.grm
OUTPUTS ID00004 PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00003.bsa
INPUTS ID00049 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00048.grm
OUTPUTS ID00049 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00048.bsa
INPUTS ID00038 FFI_0_2_txt.variation-s09877-h00000 FFI_0_2_subfx.sgt FFI_0_2_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00038 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00038.grm
INPUTS ID00027 Seismogram_FFI_0_2_ID00026.grm
OUTPUTS ID00027 PeakVals_FFI_0_2_ID00026.bsa
INPUTS ID00016 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00015.grm
OUTPUTS ID00016 PeakVals_FFI_0_1_ID00015.bsa
INPUTS ID00005 FFI_0_1_txt.variation-s01836-h00000 FFI_0_1_subfx.sgt FFI_0_1_subfy.sgt
OUTPUTS ID00005 Seismogram_FFI_0_1_ID00005.grm
EDGE ID00038 ID00039
EDGE ID00023 ID00028
EDGE ID00002 ID00017
EDGE ID00005 ID00006
EDGE ID00023 ID00040
EDGE ID00028 ID00029
EDGE ID00017 ID00018
EDGE ID00002 ID00007
EDGE ID00040 ID00041
EDGE ID00023 ID00030
EDGE ID00002 ID00019
EDGE ID00007 ID00008
EDGE ID00023 ID00042
EDGE ID00030 ID00031
EDGE ID00019 ID00020
EDGE ID00002 ID00009
EDGE ID00042 ID00043
EDGE ID00023 ID00032
EDGE ID00002 ID00021
EDGE ID00009 ID00010
EDGE ID00023 ID00044
EDGE ID00032 ID00033
EDGE ID00021 ID00022
EDGE ID00002 ID00011
EDGE ID00006 ID00000
EDGE ID00004 ID00000
EDGE ID00008 ID00000
EDGE ID00043 ID00000
EDGE ID00035 ID00000
EDGE ID00045 ID00000
EDGE ID00033 ID00000
EDGE ID00020 ID00000
EDGE ID00012 ID00000
EDGE ID00031 ID00000
EDGE ID00022 ID00000
EDGE ID00041 ID00000
EDGE ID00010 ID00000
EDGE ID00016 ID00000
EDGE ID00025 ID00000
EDGE ID00014 ID00000
EDGE ID00027 ID00000
EDGE ID00047 ID00000
EDGE ID00029 ID00000
EDGE ID00039 ID00000
EDGE ID00049 ID00000
EDGE ID00018 ID00000
EDGE ID00037 ID00000
EDGE ID00044 ID00045
EDGE ID00023 ID00034
EDGE ID00011 ID00012
EDGE ID00005 ID00001
EDGE ID00003 ID00001
EDGE ID00009 ID00001
EDGE ID00007 ID00001
EDGE ID00034 ID00001
EDGE ID00044 ID00001
EDGE ID00032 ID00001
EDGE ID00046 ID00001
EDGE ID00030 ID00001
EDGE ID00021 ID00001
EDGE ID00040 ID00001
EDGE ID00013 ID00001
EDGE ID00042 ID00001
EDGE ID00011 ID00001
EDGE ID00024 ID00001
EDGE ID00017 ID00001
EDGE ID00026 ID00001
EDGE ID00015 ID00001
EDGE ID00028 ID00001
EDGE ID00038 ID00001
EDGE ID00048 ID00001
EDGE ID00036 ID00001
EDGE ID00019 ID00001
EDGE ID00023 ID00046
EDGE ID00034 ID00035
EDGE ID00023 ID00024
EDGE ID00002 ID00013
EDGE ID00046 ID00047
EDGE ID00023 ID00036
EDGE ID00024 ID00025
EDGE ID00013 ID00014
EDGE ID00002 ID00003
EDGE ID00023 ID00048
EDGE ID00036 ID00037
EDGE ID00023 ID00026
EDGE ID00002 ID00015
EDGE ID00003 ID00004
EDGE ID00048 ID00049
EDGE ID00023 ID00038
EDGE ID00026 ID00027
EDGE ID00015 ID00016
EDGE ID00002 ID00005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use WorkflowSim which allows you to read .dax files (Workflows), which is developed in Java.

https://github.com/WorkflowSim/WorkflowSim-1.0

This works over CloudSim. 
All the details related to Cloudsim are available at http://www.cloudbus.org/cloudsim/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a code sample and not just a reference for your answer. We have guidelines on [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).